# Jenkins agent self register Windows agent to already existing Jenkins master

Tags: jenkins, terraform

I am creating a Linux server to host my application and Windows servers to run QA automation on the server through Terraform and I am having trouble finding a way to have new agents auto register themselves with the already existing master.

My current set up is I run some Terraform scripts that will create the Linux server and 3 Windows servers. Then I have to log in to the master node and Manage Jenkins -> Manage Nodes -> New Node and manually create the number of nodes I want.

Then I RDP into my agents and run the command `java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl http://yourserver:port/computer/agent-name/slave-agent.jnlp`. This works perfectly fine, but I would like a way to auto scale up/down the number of agents without having to manually log into the agents every time I create a new one.

Is there a plugin or some documentation I'm missing about how to dynamically self register nodes?

Comment: I am running a shell script mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48932624/jenkins-slave-self-register to connect the linux machine as a slave it is working fine and displays "connected" to say that slave was connected to jenkins server but the terraform scripts runs after connecting that as a slave even though all the remaining infrastructure was created successfully can anyone tell me how to exit a script by keeping it  running.

Answer (score 0):

I made a project hosted on github that automatically register a slave on jenkins, the hard stuff is here https://github.com/fredericrous/JenkinsDevEnv/blob/master/jenkins-slave-init#L26

basically what the script does is, on slave initialization

- wait for Jenkins Master to generate "agent secret" (I am sharing a volume between the slave and the master)
- make a cron to reconnect slave when connection is lost (this is an important step)
- connect the slave

this script is called as an entrypoint of my slave container https://github.com/fredericrous/JenkinsDevEnv/blob/master/docker-compose.yml#L85

I am sure this could inspire you